# How to setup an mvc partial view so that it is not affected by the css of the layout page?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-layout

In my asp.net mvc web application I have a razor layout page with a partial view `@Html.Partial("_HorizontalNavbar")` in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2020.2.513/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2020.2.513/jquery.min.js")"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2020.2.513/angular.min.js")"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2020.2.513/jszip.min.js")"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2020.2.513/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
        </head>

        <body class="k-content">
            @Html.Partial("_HorizontalNavbar")
            <main>
                <div class="container">
                    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </main>
        </body>
        </html>
```

For the partial view I do not need all the css that is referenced in the layout page; actually it interferes with the css that is inside the partial view.
Is there a way to setup a partial view so that it is not affected by the css of the layout page?
Any help will be gratefully appreciated.